# How do I install the PYEPHEM module (pip) in Termux?

Tags: android, python, module, pip, termux

I tried to install ephem or pyephem python module in Termux* but I could not. Can anybody help me?

Termux is a simulator terminal linux android app...

Comment: What was the error? (text, please, not image).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error but couldn't ¯_(ツ)_/¯[image: Installation is Successful]